# wpf maskedTextBox Databindings

Tags: wpf, maskedtextbox

I am using the following MaskedTextBox http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=MaskedTextBox in a person project for my own use. This is a simple example because i am trying to use this on a much bigger program but I am using this program to test this control.

STEPS:
1. Create a wpf application
2. Added a Linq to SQL Class called Prescriptions and added a table called info
{ID | Name | Phone}

The markup for the form is listed below:

```
<Window x:Class="MaskedTest.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:xctk="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/toolkit"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="300" Width="300"
    Loaded="Window_Loaded">
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="200"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Label Name="nameLabel" Margin="2" Target="{Binding ElementName=nameTxt}">_Full Name</Label>
    <TextBox Name="nameTxt" Grid.Column="1" Margin="2" Text="{Binding Name}"/>
    <Label Name="phoneLabel" Margin="2" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Target="{Binding ElementName=phoneTxt}">_Phone Numnber</Label>
    <xctk:MaskedTextBox Name="phoneTxt" Margin="2" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Phone}" Mask="(000) 000-0000" />
</Grid>
```

Code Behind File:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private PrescriptionDataContext pdc = new PrescriptionDataContext();
    private List<info> users = new List<info>();
    private info U = new info { Id = 1, Name = "Matthew Brown", Phone = "5128289081" };

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var q = pdc.getUser();

        foreach (info I in q)
        {
            users.Add(I);
        }

        // DOES NOT WORK
        this.DataContext = users;
        // WORKS
        // this.DataContext = U;
    }
}
```

When this loads, you will see that the name field has been binded correctly but the phone control shows only the mask not the underlying data from the table. If I explicity create the class and then bind it like i did above it works.

Ideas??

Comment: `Users` is a collection. `U` is a single object. `Users` don't have the properties that you are trying to bind to. Use an `ItemsControl` or `ListView` or something for that for displaying a list of data.

Comment: The name text field get populated by either a single user or collection of users. The Phone Field Only When I set a single user. In my other program,  it is part of a list view data bound a b day getting the same results.